# Pandas GDF as GDAL Input

Tags: python, gdal, geopandas

Afternoon,

I'm trying to use a pandas geodataframe as an input for GDAL, with the goal of utilizing the grid operation to interpolation points derived from a csv (and subsequently loaded into the gdf).

I've read it is necessary to use the gdal.OpenEx() function to convert vectors to a GDAL object, but I'm having a hard time finding useful documentation on it. There of examples of folks using an esri shapefile and driver, but nothing from a gdf.

Is the only choice to write the gdf to .shp, the .shp to storage, read it into gdal.OpenEx(), and then run the grid operation?

tl;dr: how do I load a pandas geodataframe into gdal.grid()?

Comment: Unless there's some specific feature of `gdal.Grid()` you need, my suggestion would be to use [some other scientific python library](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) to do the interpolation since your points are essentially already loaded into a numpy array.  Alternatively, you could ditch the dataframe altogether by creating a VRT that references the CSV and running that through `gdal.Grid()` directly.

Comment: @mikewatt Gotcha'. I'm mostly using gdal.Grid() because I'm familiar with the parameters. The dataframe is pretty central to the preprocessing that goes into the source csv, so I'm trying to work around it without saving a .shp to storage. Ideally everything stays in memory. On that note, the .vrt seems like the key to all of this, but I'm having trouble loading one from the ogr object I sent the geodataframe into.
`ogr_data = ogr.Open(gdf.to_json())
gdal.BuildVRT(vrt_data, ogr_data)}`
Unfortunately this throws an error: "NameError: name 'data_vrt' is not defined"

Comment: If you're going GDF->[GeoJSON](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html)->GDAL then you shouldn't need the VRT at all.  Actually, it seems [using a VRT is no longer necessary to read CSVs](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/csv.html#reading-csv-containing-spatial-information), either